# Multiplayer mode glitches, including "lost connections" and inaccessible weapons

Tags: mass-effect-3, ps3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Yesterday I was playing ME3 multiplayer for PS3. I usually use an N7 demolisher engineer with an M-7 lancer, but today when I logged in into the multiplayer, some of my weapons were gone, including the M-7 lancer.

In addition to that, the multiplayer mode in general glitches. It constantly tells me that I lost connection even before I start playing, even though I could connect with no problems at all.

Before this happened, I received two Geth infiltrators: One I used before, and the other says "new". I opened the new one and saw it was the same as my old one. I exited the character appearance screen then the problem happened.